# Python: Is it possible to condense my list of similar methods

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a list of ID's that I am capturing using Selenium IDE and placing them into PyCharm. The list looks like this:

```
filter_logs_query = (By.ID, "Query")
filter_logs_FromDateUI = (By.ID, "FromDateUI")
filter_logs_ToDateUI = (By.ID, "ToDateUI")
filter_logs_Ip = (By.ID, "Ip")
filter_logs_User = (By.ID, "User")  
filter_logs_Message = (By.ID, "Message")
filter_logs_RefID = (By.ID, "Refid")
filter_logs_Session = (By.ID, "Session")
filter_logs_Scope = (By.ID, "Scope")
filter_logs_EventNo = (By.ID, "EventNo")
filter_logs_Server = (By.ID, "Server")
```

Each of these ID's also has a def for a user to send_keys to the ID, the list look like this:

```
def filter_logs_search_query(self, word):
    search_text = self.driver.find_element(*Elements.filter_logs_query)
    search_text.send_keys(word)

def filter_logs_logged_after(self, word):
    search_date = self.driver.find_element(*Elements.filter_logs_FromDateUI)
    search_date.send_keys(word)

def filter_logs_logged_before(self, word):
    search_date = self.driver.find_element(*Elements.filter_logs_ToDateUI)
    search_date.send_keys(word)
```

My defs are nearly identical aside from the function I need to call from *Elements. Is there a way I could possibly condense/shorten my list of def's?

Comment: Create a function that holds all the common code, and pass in as an parameter the function that differs.

Comment: If you ask me, it's not bad at all to have those `def` statements. You have good function names that describe the work getting done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a job for [Higher Order Functions.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function)

Whenever you have a case where code is the same, *except* for a function being called, it can be a good idea to just pass that function in (note `f`):

```
def general_filter_logs(self, word, f):
    search_text = self.driver.find_element(*f)
    search_text.send_keys(word)
```

Then, the other functions can be defined in terms of the generalized higher-order function. For example:

```
def filter_logs_search_query(self, word):
    general_filter_logs(word, Elements.filter_logs_query)
```

Note, your repetitious functions aren't very big, so the gain here isn't huge. This technique becomes especially helpful with more complicated functions though. The benefit you always get by generalizing a function is if you ever need to make a change to it, you only need to change one function (the general function) instead of all the "clone" functions.

Also note that this appears to be the technique `find_element` uses! Instead of forcing you to write your own custom find method, it allows you to just pass a function in. All you need to do now is just push back the responsibility of who is responsible for picking what function gets passed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are already sending a string with the key type. Use an if statement or make a dictionary that uses the string as the key.

Define the dictionary in the constructor:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.query_map = {'Message':Elements.filter_logs_mesage, 'Session':Elements.filter_logs_session} # etc
```

Then use the dictionary to "select" the elements:

```
    def filter_logs_search(self, word):
        search_text = self.driver.find_element(self.query_map[word]) 
search_text.send_keys(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the whole thing could be compacted to

```
class FilterClass:
    fields = {
        "query": "Query",
        "before": "FromDateUI",
        "after": "ToDateUI",
        "ip": "Ip",
        "user": "User",
        "msg": "Message",
        "ref": "Refid",
        "session": "Session",
        "scope": "Scope",
        "event": "EventNo",
        "server": "Server"
    }

    def filter_logs(self, field, value):
        search = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, self.fields[field])
        search.send_keys(value)
```